# Removing controls

Tags: .net, vb.net, controls

I have a lot of buttons on a form (144) that need to be removed. All their names begin with "R". So I used this piece of code.

```
Sub RemoveBookingButtons()
    Dim cntrl As Control

    For Each cntrl In Me.Controls
        If Mid(cntrl.name, 1, 1) = "R" Then
            Me.Controls.Remove(cntrl)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

However whenever I run this sub function, it deletes every other button starting with "R". Could someone suggest better code or point out if the flaw is in that piece of code or it is hidden somewhere else in my program.

Comment: Did you mean every other button or every other control? because in this loop you are iterating over all of your controls(not only buttons). To iterate over only buttons you could use `For Each btn As Button In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button)()`

Comment: Could you explain your requirement? _"However whenever I run this sub function, it deletes every other button starting with 'R'"_. I would have assumed that this would be your desired behaviour, isn't it?

Comment: @Tim Schmelter That means if I have 144 buttons, it deletes 72 of them. Run the routine again and it deletes 36 of them. So on so forth.

Answer (score 2):

Don't change a `Collection` during iteration.

You could use [`OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) to find all your `Buttons`:

```
Dim rButtons = Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button)().
    Where(Function(btn) btn.Name.StartsWith("R")).ToList()
For Each btn In rButtons
    Me.Controls.Remove(btn)
Next
```

To **clarify** this code:

In general this is [LINQ-to-Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx).

```
Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button)()
```

This returns all controls in the form's [`ControlCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.controlcollection.aspx) [of Type `Button`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx).

```
.Where(Function(btn) btn.Name.StartsWith("R"))
```

This limits the resultset to buttons which `Name` [`StartsWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith.aspx) "R"(note that this is case sensitive and you'd need to call `ToLower/ToUpper` first if want it to be case insenstive).

```
.ToList()
```

This creates a `List(Of Button)` from the `IEnumerable(OfButton)`. Not that any LINQ  query will be executed deferred. [Deferred execution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943859.aspx) means that the evaluation of an expression is delayed until its realized value is actually required. So the query does not materialize until anything consumes it, in this case the `ToList()` which executes it and creates the list as well.

Comment: Hey, could you explain the first two lines of your code. I understand that you obtain a list of all the buttons starting with R and then use the For loop to delete the entire list. What does the "Where" function thing do?

Comment: @PejmanPoh: Edited my answer to explain the code a bit. Have a look at the links tio get more informations.

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying the collection you're iterating over, so it's bound to go wrong.  I'm surprised it even runs.

You should retrieve all matching controls into a new list, then iterate over that list, removing from the first.

In C#:

```
var toRemove = this.Controls.Where( ctrl => ctrl.Name.StartsWith("R") ).ToList();
foreach( var ctrl in toRemove )
{
    this.Controls.Remove(ctrl);
}
```

In VB:

```
dim toRemove = (from c in Me.Controls where c.StartsWith("R") select c).ToList()

for each ctrl in toRemove
  Me.Controls.Remove(ctrl)
next
```

Answer (score 0):

The minimal approach to resolve your problems is to use a For loop instead a For Each,
Starting from the end of the Controls collection as in

```
For i = Me.Controls.Count -1 To 0
  Dim cntrl as Control = Me.Controls(i)
  If Mid(cntrl.name, 1, 1) = "R" Then 
      Me.Controls.Remove(cntrl) 
  End If 
Next
```